# Create a different Windows account for compiling?

Tags: windows, open-source, compilation, accounts

I am experimenting with different open source projects just to see which one I can work with since I am a beginner. Of course, many projects have different dependencies and programs that you must install. I want to keep things organized and I don't want to pollute my main windows account, since I use this machine for everyday computing also.

Will creating a seperate windows account on my computer help separate the dependencies for the projects? Are there any better alternatives (other than using virtual machines)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you mentioned other than them, but virtual machines are actually the best option if you're planning on working with a lot of different projects and you don't want to pollute your environment too much.  If you build them right, you can have a baseline VM that is simple to revert back to if you want to start from scratch because the environment got too polluted.

The problem with only using a separate account is that many installable tools and libraries means they're still going to be made available for all users on the machine, so it doesn't keep things cleaned up.  For example, if Visual Studio tools typically apply to all users on the machine.  COM dependencies aren't user specific.  Some things install Windows Services that need to be running most of the time, but you don't use unless you're developing for them (like SQL Server Reporting Services).

Answer (score 0):

How about installing many kinds of operation system?

If you have enough money, you can buy a computer only for experiment

Answer (score 0):

Virtual machines is definitely the way to go - most non-trivial software modifies more than HKEY_CURRENT_USER machine state. If you don't want full-blown virtual machines (but oh, they're sweet, especially the ones supporting state snapshots!) you could look at something like [sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/).